# разбить дамп вики на части

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Подскажите, как разбить дамп википедии на читаемые части (всю вики обработать не могу, так как компьютер не потянет doc2vec по всей вики). Дамп брала отсюда пару месяцев назад https://dumps.wikimedia.org/ruwiki/latest/ , пробовала разбить на части winrarом, но сейчас думаю, что лучше как-то в самом python, пытаюсь отыскать что-то в gensim.corpora , но пока безуспешно

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос (кнопка `править`) ссылку на дамп и то как вы пытались с ним работать

Comment: Не совсем понятно как вы пытались прочитать эти файлы. По одному тоже не получается? Можете показать ваш код?

Comment: Сейчас прочла так: from gensim.corpora.wikicorpus import WikiCorpus   wiki = WikiCorpus("ruwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml.bz2"). Пытаюсь разобраться, как несколько статей вытащить

Comment: @Liza, `Doc2Vec()` работает для данного корпуса?

Comment: [попробуйте так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6411933/5741205)

Comment: Кстати [отсюда](http://rusvectores.org/ru/models/) можно скачать готовые модели для различных русскоязычных корпусов...

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо, попробую, а готовые модели, вроде, для word2vec

Comment: @MaxU, Doc2Vec() работает на таком корпусе, но это очень ресурсоёмкий алгоритм и мой ноутбук с 8 гигами оперативки не потянет всю википедию

Comment: @Liza, для чего вам векторизировать всю википедию? Может воспользуетесь готовыми моделями?

Comment: @MaxU, я б с удовольствием, но готовые только для Word2Vec есть

Comment: @Liza, пардон, не обратил внимание, что вам `doc2vec` нужен... И все таки, что вы хотите делать с этой моделью?

Comment: @MaxU, вообще хотелось научиться со всем этим работать, а так как парсинг я пока не освоила, а открытых источников информации с данными не особо много...А так в планах что-то вроде рекомендательной системы статей, книг

Comment: @Liza, обучать модель по частям - нетривиальная задача. Сначала придется заранее построить словарь (слов) по всем частям корпуса, а вот как быть потом - как "доучивать" модель для каждой новой части, причем так, чтобы не испортить векторы (embeddings)?

Comment: @MaxU, да я понимаю, еще немного повожусь, если не получится, пойду осваивать парсинг)

Comment: @Liza я не знаю что такое doc2vec, но, как я понял, что-то из машинного обучения на основе текста статей Википедии? Окей, а зачем вам для этого разбивать винраром дамп? Дамп — это цельная база со своей структурой. Разбив винраром, вы эту структуру нарушите. Почему вы не можете ограничить область чтения тупо до определённого порядкового номера (id) страницы? Если хотите разбить весь массив на пачки, ну так и разбивайте взависимости от id страниц. Пусть в одном документе (да хоть в текстовом!) у вас будет текст статей с 0 по 1000, в другом — далее.

Comment: @Liza и зачем вам вообще что-то парсить? Нет, понятно, вам придётся избавляться от викиразметки в тексте статей, но сам тест статей и id страниц из дампа получается четырьмя строками кода и без разархивирования дампа. А дальше «делай с ним что хош».